# How to make the 'read' function start from the beginning of the file?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a binary file and I am using the `f_in.read((char(*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp))` function.  However, each time I call this function it continues reading the file from the position where the previous read function had left off.  Is it possible to make the read function start from the beginning of the file each time it is called?

Opening the pixmap.bin file:

```
int main(){

    ifstream f_in;
    f_in.open("Pixmap.bin", ios::binary);

    if (f_in.fail()) {

        cerr<<"Error while opening the file pixmap.bin"<<endl;
        f_in.close();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

The function that I want to use with read starting from the beginning each time:

```
void Read_Dimensions(ifstream &f_in, int Dimensions[2]) {

    uint tmp(0);
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++) {

        f_in.read((char*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
        Dimensions[i]=tmp;

    }

    }
```

Comment: What is `f_in`? You need to post code that others can run

Comment: I'm guessing `f_n` is `(i)fstream`? if so `seekg` should do the work

Comment: I have edited the text of the question. @David Haim , what does the seek function do?

Comment: @Mandralis Bookmark [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=seekg).

Comment: Start with learning basic file I/O concepts and terms, then [a `std::istream` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) should help.

Comment: Why do you want to read the same data multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is relative to the file pointer, try reading this page in the section '**File pointer**':
http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/cppBinaryFileIO-2.html

Here the example the give:

```
int main()
{
  int x;
  streampos pos;
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("silly.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
  infile.seekp(243, ios::beg); // move 243 bytes into the file
  infile.read(&x, sizeof(x));
  pos = infile.tellg();
  cout << "The file pointer is now at location " << pos << endl;
  infile.seekp(0,ios::end); // seek to the end of the file
  infile.seekp(-10, ios::cur); // back up 10 bytes
  infile.close();
}
```

Wish that helps you.